# Handling C# exceptions in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, exception, c++-cli

I have a tricky combination of C#, C++/CLI and native C++ code. In short, what I have:

1. A third-party managed application, namely, the Visual Studio 2010 process
2. A C++/CLI dll which is loaded by this process, namely, an [Evaluator Add-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fwk67y3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
3. A C# assembly with a `Windows.Froms.Form` class in it, which is shown by the dll

I show my C# form from the C++/CLI dll with the `ShowDialog` method:

```
System::Reflection::Assembly^ GUI = System::Reflection::Assembly::LoadFrom("MyCppDll.dll");
Type^ FormMain = GUI->GetType("MyCsNamespace.FormMain");
MethodInfo^ ShowDialog = FormMain->GetMethod("ShowDialog", gcnew array<Type^>{});
System::Object^ form = System::Activator::CreateInstance(FormMain, args);
ShowDialog->Invoke(form, nullptr);
```

All works fine, except I don't know how to handle exceptions which may be thrown during form execution. I wish the `ShowDialog->Invoke` call just throws these exceptions, but it ain't.

I've tried to set `AppDomain::UnhandledException` handler in C++, but it is not triggered. The weird thing, I tried to set it in C#, but it is not triggered either.

So how do I handle exceptions in C++ dll which is thrown in C# assembly in this situation? I have full control over C++ and C# code, but the host application is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ShowDialog->Invoke` will throw a TargetInvocationException; the InnerException of this will be the exception that the form throws.

Comment: You are exactly right! I was fooled by my launcher application I used to mimic Visual Studio as a host process. In that case, for some reason, in Release configuration I got this error dialog: http://i.stack.imgur.com/M2PyO.png Any ideas why?